# Sapphire HD 4870 GDDR 512 drivers for Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, graphics

I just installed a new graphic card, could someone tell me how can I install the drivers for **Sapphire HD 4870 GDDR 512** ?

Unfortunately I only see Windows driver on their official website.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple drivers, a opensource one which probably is already going under the hood if your ubuntu version is not too old.
The other option is to install the clumsy and often bugged/outdated driver via synaptics (search for fglrx or catalyst)

Answer (score 0):

It's a branded ATI/AMD card, [you can use AMD's drivers](http://support.amd.com/br/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx).